# How can I pass a function as an optional parameter in C++?

Tags: c++

I have two functions that are quite similar, so I'm trying reduce the code duplication. I thought I can create a new function `MyFunction()` **that be called** both with or without a `func` that can be optionally applied to the arguments. So the default for `func` should be a function that just returns `i`. I'm not sure if my code is correct and also couldn't find out how to define a default function. I have something like this (comment out `MyFunction` to run the code)

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int somefunc(int b, int i){
    return i-b; // simplified
}

std::vector<int> MyOldFunction1(const int a,
                            std::vector<int> list) {
          std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), list.begin(), 
                      [a](int i) -> int {return a*i;});
       return list;
}

std::vector<int> MyOldFunction2(const int a,
                            std::vector<int> list,
                            const int b) {
          std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), list.begin(), 
                      [a,b](int i) -> int {return a*somefunc(b,i);});
       return list;
}

// Suggested combination (not working)
std::vector<int> MyFunction(const int a,
                            std::vector<int> list, std::function<int,int> &f,
                            const int b) {
          std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), list.begin(), 
                      [a,b](int i) -> int {return a*f(b,i);});
       return list;
}

void PrintVector(std::vector<int> a) {
    for(auto i=a.begin(); i!=a.end(); ++i){
        std::cout<<(*i);
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}


int main () {
    int p[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> a(p, p+5);
    PrintVector(MyOldFunction1(1,a)); // 1,2,3,4,5
    PrintVector(MyOldFunction2(1,a,1)); // 0,1,2,3,4

}
```

Is there a more efficient/clean way to do this? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `std::optional` and then selection inside the function, how about using plain overloading?

Comment: fwiw, posting a [mcve] helps really a lot to write an answer. To write an answer I need to add includes, and to test my answer I will have to write a main with a small test. Thats things you should have already

Comment: I find the interface highly confusing. Rather than an optional `func` *and* an optional `b`, it rather just let the user pass a `func`. If they need a `b` then can let the callable capture it. Your current implementation is also prone to errors, when no `b` is passed then the caller has to handle that in `f`.

Comment: thanks for the fast replies. let me edit my post

Comment: Also you can't modify a `const` parameter.

Comment: Strange function argument selection and order (especially version containing `b` and `f` - `b` looks obsolete). Also you anonymized code to much so it is hard to propose something more idiomatic and more readable.

Comment: First of all `std::function<int,int>` is not valid. The signature for `somefunc` is `int(int, int)` which should be the type for the function object: `std::function<int(int, int)>`. Secondly I suggest you take a hint from the C++ standard library and its functions that take callable objects: Use templates. Like `template<typename F> std::vector<int>& MyFunction(int a, std::vector<int>& list, F f);`. Now you can use any callable object (lambdas, suitable `std::function` or `std::bind` objects, plain function pointers, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a default parameter of type `std::function<int(int)>`, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> MyFunction(const int a, 
                            std::vector<int> list, 
                            std::function<int(int)> func = [](int i) -> int { return i; }) {
    std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), list.begin(), [a, func](int i) -> int { return a*func(i); });
   return list;    
}
```

You can then pass a lambda that calls `somefunc` with your `b`, e.g.

```
[b = 2](int i) -> int { return somefunc(b, i); }
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e9401c675e331dd)

Aside: You need to drop the `const` from the parameter `list` if you intend to modify it in the body.

Further aside: With C++20 you can template this and still communicate that `func` must accept an `int` and return an `int`:

```
template<typename Func = decltype([](int i) -> int { return i; })>
requires(std::is_invocable_r_v<int, Func, int>)
std::vector<int> MyFunction(const int a, 
                            std::vector<int> list, 
                            Func func = {}) {
    std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), list.begin(), [a, func](int i) -> int { return a*func(i); });
   return list;    
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the second use-case requires a `std::function<int(int, int)>`, not a `std::function<int(int)>` (two parameters)

Comment: @Fareanor it needs a `(int, int) -> int` and an `int`, so you may as well partially apply in the caller

Comment: Oh you're right, I like this solution :)

Comment: I use C++11 and the above only works for 14 onwards >.<

Comment: @user3710760 I was using that initialiser in place of a `b` defined elsewhere. `int b = 2; ... MyFunction(1, list, [b](int i) -> int { return somefunc(b, i); })` would work, as would `MyFunction(1, list, [](int i) -> int { return somefunc(2, i); })`